# Fixed distance buffer version 2.16.1 problems

Tags: qgis, shapefile, usgs

I am trying to buffer a simple line and the program simply won't complete the process after 10 attempts. I am buffering to 20,000 (I assume it's metres). Anyone had this issue before? My internet is fine and I restarted QGIS too. I am new to the programme.

Comment: Are you SURE it's in meters? what's the layer's CRS?

Comment: please add some details about the data set you are buffering to the question

Comment: hi, it says USER:10002(OTF)

Comment: Sorry my computer is crashing constantly because of the buffer fail. the layer's CRS is EPSG 4326, WGS 84 CRS. the sata set is a set of fault lines (San Andreas Fault)

Comment: If the input is in WGS84, the buffer size is in degrees, not in meters. You need to reproject the input data

Comment: Many thanks. I'll look up how to do that ASAP. Thanks again